# Formula to adjust a note by cents

Tags: frequency

I'm trying to find a formula to adjust a note frequency by a variable number of cents. So for example if a middle C was played then how do you find "N" cents adjustment to that frequency? I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

I thought it was something like:

`x * (1 + (N * 0.00057778951))`

where x is the original frequency, but it just doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cent is the 1200th part of an octave which is a factor of 2.

Consequently, an adjustment of N cents means multiplying your frequency by 2<sup>N/1200</sup>.

Comment: So using my formula it would be x*2^(y/1200). That seems to be what I'm looking for, since making y=100 changes the note by 1 semitone.